# computing and inference of many spark kernel density estimators in parallel

Tags: pyspark

I'd like to do

1. segmented or groupBy pyspark kernel density estimation
2. Join the resulting density estimators to another dataframe and do inference

For example, imagine I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data=[{'id':1, 'samples':[3,56,40]},
      {'id':2, 'samples':[-3,80,45,45,2]}]
```

This data was generated from something like

```
df.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list('sample').alias('samples'))
```

where `df` is big. Then imagine I have another dataframe that is big, data like:

```
data2 = [{'id':1, 'val': 10},
         {'id':1, 'val': 39},
         {'id':2, 'val': 5}]
```

I'd like to get the probabilities for the those three values, 10, 39, 5 with respect to the two density estimators I got above.

For example, a Python program that would do this would be

```
import scipy.stats

data_to_define_pdfs=[{'id':1, 'samples':[3,56,40]},
                     {'id':2, 'samples':[-3,80,45,45,2]}]
kdes = {}
for row in data_to_define_pdfs:
    kdes[row['id']] = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(row['samples'])

inferrence_data = [
    {'id': 1, 'val': 10},
    {'id': 1, 'val': 39},
    {'id': 2, 'val': 5}]

for row in inferrence_data:
    kde = kdes[row['id']]
    row['prob'] = kde.pdf(x=row['val'])[0]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(inferrence_data)
```

which would output

```
[{'id': 1, 'prob': 0.008817584549791962, 'val': 10},
 {'id': 1, 'prob': 0.012149240532443975, 'val': 39},
 {'id': 2, 'prob': 0.008013522166302479, 'val': 5}]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the desired output as well and some explanation of explicitly how it's calculated.

Comment: Thanks for interest! I added an example.

Comment: Did you find any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution where I join all the samples with the data for inference, its not optimal as I may replicate a lot of samples, and I'm regenerating the python scipy kde object for each row in the data where I apply the kde - but its a start, I can imagine doing something smarter:

```
data_to_define_pdfs_flat = []
for row in data:
    for sample in row['samples']:
        data_to_define_pdfs_flat.append({'id':row['id'], 'sample': sample})

df_sample = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_to_define_pdfs_flat,
                                  schema=T.StructType([T.StructField('id', T.IntegerType(), False),
                                                       T.StructField('sample', T.FloatType(), False)]))
df_samples = df_sample.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list('sample').alias('samples'))

df_infer = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,
                                 schema=T.StructType([T.StructField('id', T.IntegerType(), False),
                                                      T.StructField('val', T.FloatType(), False)]))

df_infer2 = df_infer.join(df_samples, on='id')


def do_inference(df):
    def f(samples, val):
        kde = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(samples)
        return float(kde.pdf(val)[0])

    udf_f = F.udf(f, T.FloatType())
    return df.withColumn('prob', udf_f(F.col('samples'), F.col('val')))


df_infer2 = do_inference(df=df_infer2)
df_samples.show()
df_infer2.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can store all the samples for the KDE's locally, I have a pandas dataframe solution - at least with this toy example. It always seems hard to get pandas dataframe stuff to work at scale because of how it uses memory.

In this solution, the kde's are all formed on the master node and shipped to all the task nodes - each kde is a function of all the sample data for that id, so I'll have to subsample the data that makes `df_samples`:

```
def do_inference_pd(df_infer, df_samples):
    rows = df_samples.collect()
    kdes = {}
    for row in rows:
        row = row.asDict(True)
        kdes[row['id']] = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(np.array(row['samples']))

    def kde_prob(pdf):
        kde = kdes[pdf.id[0]]
        x = pdf.val
        return pdf.assign(prob=kde(x))

    df_infer_prob = df_infer.withColumn('prob', F.lit(0.0))
    sch_str = df_infer2.schema.simpleString()
    f = F.pandas_udf(f=kde_prob, returnType=sch_str, functionType=F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    df_infer_prob = df_infer_prob.groupBy('id').apply(f)
    return df_infer_prob


df_infer_prob = do_inference_pd(df_infer=df_infer, df_samples=df_samples)
```